# mongodb population vs diverging data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have 2 document types, a and b, a references b and can point to the same b for multiple a's.
so different "a" docs can point to the same "b" doc, the reference to b is held in a via an _id

a--b

a-/

a--b

assume there are tens/hundreds of thousands of entries for each.

assume there is a certain variable that is kept in b but i also need it when i query for a. 
what is better, storing that variable 2 times in a and b which causes divergence but lets me not have to populate b just to get that single piece  of data or populating tens of thousands of a documents per query with b?

idk this would not be an issue in a normal database engine like sql or postgres but I already have alot of the source code using mongodb with mongoose and its a bit too late to switch now.